# Disable status bar flashing on send/receive in Outlook 2013?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013

Is there any way to stop Outlook flashing the status bar on every send/receive?

Comment: I think you can hide the bar. It's the status bar I think or did you want to keep it open at the same time ?

Comment: I don't want to get rid of the whole status bar, just the send/receive message and progress bar that flashes up on the status bar.